# 'Get-Service' fails to list *all* services due to one causing an issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-registry, windows-services

As a "normal" UAC-elevated user (i.e. member of the `BUILTIN\Administrators` alias, *but not* `.\Administrator`), how can I list all services using `Get-Service` and sidestep the issue described below? How can I diagnose the issue further?

In the course of a more complex script, I was trying to enumerate all services on my system. Simply issuing a `Get-Service` on the (elevated) PowerShell prompt gave me the following (excerpt):

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
[...]
Running  DcomLaunch         DCOM Server Process Launcher
Get-Service: Service 'dcsvc (dcsvc)' cannot be queried due to the following error:
Get-Service: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It won't proceed past the `dcsvc` (aka "Declared Configuration (DC) service"). I am reproducing the exported registry key at the bottom of the question.

My immediate reaction was to use `-ErrorAction` to squelch the error and have it proceed ... alas:

```
~$ Get-Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "Wallet*" }
Get-Service: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And indeed even in the Services snap-in I am seeing:

[image: After double-clicking the dcsvc entry]

`Get-Service -Name dcsvc` gives the same error.

The issue here isn't so much about permissions but the fact that `Get-Service` won't do its job and simply fails the enumeration at first sight of the error, instead of proceeding and giving me a cumulative error state at the end.

**Further observations:**

- The error appears to be potentially related to a permissions issue, despite the elevated prompt. Using `psexec` and running `services.msc` (or PowerShell) as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` shows that I can successfully enumerate *all* services.
- The issue happens both in scripts and on the interactive prompt.
- I was unable to see a security descriptor (SD) from the object retrieved in PowerShell, but am able to retrieve the SD via `(Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc).sddl`, which gives me (with added line breaks for readability):

  ```
  O:SY
  G:SY
  D:AI
    (A;CIID;KR;;;BU)
    (A;CIID;KA;;;BA)
    (A;CIID;KA;;;SY)
    (A;CIIOID;KA;;;CO)
    (A;CIID;KR;;;AC)
    (A;CIID;KR;;;S-1-15-3-1024-1065365936-1281604716-3511738428-1654721687-432734479-3232135806-4053264122-3456934681)
  ```

  I am pretty much positive that the `(A;CIID;KA;;;BA)` ACE should give me all the needed access from an elevated prompt, but still something is failing. But I am not a 100% certain if the SD of the `Services` subkey coincides with the SD of the service or not.
- The SDs on the subkeys (`Parameters`, `TriggerInfo`, `TriggerInfo\0`, `TriggerInfo\1`) are all exactly the same as on the top-level key.
- When using the form `Get-Service "Wallet*"`, for example, I am able to list the matching services, but it's still impossible to enumerate all of them.
- Issue persists when booting into Safe Mode, too.
- The SDs were the exact same (going by the SDDL output) on an unrelated Windows 10 Pro (19044) and Windows 11 Pro N (22000) installation. Down to that trustee in the last ACE.
- Problem persists even after `sfc /scannow && dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` (for `sfc` even with "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.")

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc]
"DelayedAutoStart"=dword:00000001
"DependOnService"=hex(7):72,00,70,00,63,00,73,00,73,00,00,00,00,00
"Description"="@%systemroot%\\system32\\dcsvc.dll,-101"
"DisplayName"="@%systemroot%\\system32\\dcsvc,-100"
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"FailureActions"=hex:80,51,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
  00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
; ImagePath = "%systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p"
"ImagePath"=hex(2):25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,76,00,63,00,68,00,6f,00,73,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,\
  6b,00,20,00,6e,00,65,00,74,00,73,00,76,00,63,00,73,00,20,00,2d,00,70,00,00,\
  00
"ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
"ServiceSidType"=dword:00000001
"Start"=dword:00000003
"Type"=dword:00000010

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc\Parameters]
"IdleTimeout(sec)"=dword:00000078
; ServiceDll = "%SystemRoot%\system32\dcsvc.dll"
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
  64,00,63,00,73,00,76,00,63,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ServiceDllUnloadOnStop"=dword:00000001
"ServiceMain"="ServiceMain"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc\TriggerInfo]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc\TriggerInfo\0]
"Action"=dword:00000001
"Data0"=hex:35,00,39,00,62,00,65,00,62,00,39,00,37,00,37,00,2d,00,64,00,30,00,\
  33,00,37,00,2d,00,34,00,38,00,66,00,34,00,2d,00,61,00,66,00,37,00,34,00,2d,\
  00,63,00,61,00,30,00,37,00,35,00,34,00,39,00,33,00,61,00,35,00,32,00,33,00,\
  00,00
"DataType0"=dword:00000002
"GUID"=hex:67,d1,90,bc,70,94,39,41,a9,ba,be,0b,bb,f5,b7,4d
"Type"=dword:00000006

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc\TriggerInfo\1]
"Action"=dword:00000001
"Data0"=hex:30,00,61,00,30,00,64,00,62,00,36,00,31,00,34,00,2d,00,65,00,39,00,\
  66,00,62,00,2d,00,34,00,38,00,63,00,66,00,2d,00,39,00,31,00,34,00,33,00,2d,\
  00,37,00,61,00,65,00,37,00,31,00,38,00,66,00,66,00,32,00,63,00,38,00,33,00,\
  00,00
"DataType0"=dword:00000002
"GUID"=hex:67,d1,90,bc,70,94,39,41,a9,ba,be,0b,bb,f5,b7,4d
"Type"=dword:00000006
```

Note: I added the plain text value of the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values just above each of them as a comment.

Another thing to note is the value for `DisplayName`, which does not refer to a valid DLL, and thus resource. However, I checked the values both in an unrelated (and moreover otherwise clean) installation of Windows 10 Pro (19044) and an equally pristine Windows 11 Pro N (22000) — same thing.

State of the files mentioned in the registry:

```
C:\>dir /b %systemroot%\\system32\\dcsvc.dll
dcsvc.dll

C:\>dir /b %systemroot%\\system32\\dcsvc
File Not Found

C:\>dir /b %SystemRoot%\system32\dcsvc.dll
dcsvc.dll

C:\>dir /b %systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe
svchost.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I note that if in my computer I double-click in Services on `dcscv` -
I get exactly the same error! However, `Get-Service` terminates
well for PowerShell that is run as Administrator and I can find
`dcsvc` in the list.

Question: Does the file `%systemroot%\system32\dcsvc.dll` exist
on your computer?

I suggest running `chkdsk` to verify the file-system.

You could verify your registry contents against mine for
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc`.
Mine are listed below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc]
"DelayedAutoStart"=dword:00000001
"DependOnService"=hex(7):72,00,70,00,63,00,73,00,73,00,00,00,00,00
"Description"="@%systemroot%\\system32\\dcsvc.dll,-101"
"DisplayName"="@%systemroot%\\system32\\dcsvc,-100"
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"FailureActions"=hex:80,51,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
  00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"ImagePath"=hex(2):25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,76,00,63,00,68,00,6f,00,73,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,\
  6b,00,20,00,6e,00,65,00,74,00,73,00,76,00,63,00,73,00,20,00,2d,00,70,00,00,\
  00
"ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
"ServiceSidType"=dword:00000001
"Start"=dword:00000003
"Type"=dword:00000010

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc\Parameters]
"IdleTimeout(sec)"=dword:00000078
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
  64,00,63,00,73,00,76,00,63,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ServiceDllUnloadOnStop"=dword:00000001
"ServiceMain"="ServiceMain"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc\TriggerInfo]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc\TriggerInfo\0]
"Action"=dword:00000001
"Data0"=hex:35,00,39,00,62,00,65,00,62,00,39,00,37,00,37,00,2d,00,64,00,30,00,\
  33,00,37,00,2d,00,34,00,38,00,66,00,34,00,2d,00,61,00,66,00,37,00,34,00,2d,\
  00,63,00,61,00,30,00,37,00,35,00,34,00,39,00,33,00,61,00,35,00,32,00,33,00,\
  00,00
"DataType0"=dword:00000002
"GUID"=hex:67,d1,90,bc,70,94,39,41,a9,ba,be,0b,bb,f5,b7,4d
"Type"=dword:00000006

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcsvc\TriggerInfo\1]
"Action"=dword:00000001
"Data0"=hex:30,00,61,00,30,00,64,00,62,00,36,00,31,00,34,00,2d,00,65,00,39,00,\
  66,00,62,00,2d,00,34,00,38,00,63,00,66,00,2d,00,39,00,31,00,34,00,33,00,2d,\
  00,37,00,61,00,65,00,37,00,31,00,38,00,66,00,66,00,32,00,63,00,38,00,33,00,\
  00,00
"DataType0"=dword:00000002
"GUID"=hex:67,d1,90,bc,70,94,39,41,a9,ba,be,0b,bb,f5,b7,4d
"Type"=dword:00000006
```

If all else fails, I would suggest to do a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so take the same
precautions. It will preserve your apps, data and almost all settings.
But it might return the file that seems to be missing on your computer.

Comment: Thanks. The registry files are the same, with the exception of the comments I inserted to show the plain text values of `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. `dcsvc.dll` exists, yes (`dcsvc.dl` doesn't). I don't quite understand your second sentence, though. It does or does not fail when elevated? Or are you talking about the builtin `Administrator` (RID == 500)? Also, isn't DISM supposed to do exactly what you suggest? Verify the integrity of the current live image against what it ought to be and -- optionally -- repair?

Comment: Double-click inside the Services applet GUI fails with same error. PowerShell `Get-Service` does not fail and gives a list that includes `dcsvc`.